# Javascript Window.Open Dimensions

Tags: javascript

I'm opening a new window from javascript using this code

```
window.open('index.htm', 'myWindow', 'width=1020,height=400');
```

However the window seems to be opening 10px too wide when measuring from outter border to outer border, I've only tested this on IE7 and IE8 so far. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the IE Blog for details on how Microsoft changed their window dimensions in IE7 (and beyond)

**IE Blog:** [Why Does IE Resize My Dialogs?](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/08/25/719355.aspx)

Quotes:

IE6 gives web developers control over the frame size of dialogs (also known as the ‘chrome’). The frame includes visual elements such as the title bar, status bar, borders, etc. This is a problem for web developers because the dialog’s frame size varies according to whatever windows theme is applied (this is bad)...

In Windows XP Service Pack 2, IE’s security improvements added window restrictions that forced the status bar onto windows and dialogs (in certain security zones); developers adapted by subtracting the height of the status bar from their dialogs...

Before the guesswork for sizing the content area gets any worse for developers, we felt it was time to set things right by focusing on delivering HTML content area instead of total frame size.

Here’s how we changed it. In IE7, the meaning of window.dialogHeight and dialogWidth now refers to the content area. Essentially, the area (height/width) that you specify is what we try to deliver in the content area of the dialog (barring window restrictions on scriptable minimum sizes: 250px wide x 150px high*). It will no longer be necessary to calculate the area lost by components of a dialog’s frame.

**Figure 3**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

window.onload=setTimeout(function(){window.open('http://www.w3schools.com', 'myWindow', 'width=920,height=400');},1000);